# Get value from input number Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to recover a value from an input with ionic 2 and angular 2.
I want a value of type number.

My HTML :

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input id = "choosenNumber" type="number" value=4 ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

My TypeScript :

```
var input_element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("choosenNumber");
var choosenNumberValue = input_element.valueAsNumber; //does not work !! (valueAsNumber undefined)
```

The code does not work because `input_element.valueAsNumber` is undefined.

Comment: If you use angular 2, you shouldn't do things like it. 
var input_element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("choosenNumber");

Comment: You don't have to (or rather, you should not) edit the title to tell us that the question is solved, that is already visible since you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I've found the solution by using [(ngModel)]. Thanks

Here is the solution : 
[HTML]

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="chVal" name = "chVal" value=4 ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

[TS]

```
export class MyClass{
   chVal:number;
```

chVal is the good value !!